# Tag destino - rastreamento correios (JAVA)

Tags: java, api, web-service

Boa tarde pessoal!

Estou trabalhando com a manutenção de uma aplicação JAVA integrada ao ERP J.D. Edwards, onde temos uma interface para recuperar informações de código de rastreio dos correios.

Porém, a tag "destino" dentro da tag "evento" na API "buscaEventos", não está retornando na aplicação nenhuma informação. Já tentei identificar um ou outro ponto que poderia estar causando esse problema (como import do package "oracle.e1.bssv.JC554901.proxyRastreio.types.Destinos"), porém nada parece resolver esse problema.

No SoapUI, consigo ver a informação retornando corretamente, porém de forma alguma consigo ver essa informação no JDeveloper.

```html
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <X-OPNET-Transaction-Trace:X-OPNET-Transaction-Trace xmlns:X-OPNET-Transaction-Trace="http://opnet.com">pid=152686,requestid=af7a9756ee9e245409e56f9f101ebf9d66f23581c8b19a22</X-OPNET-Transaction-Trace:X-OPNET-Transaction-Trace>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ns2:buscaEventosResponse xmlns:ns2="http://resource.webservice.correios.com.br/">
         <return>
            <versao>2.0</versao>
            <qtd>1</qtd>
            <objeto>
               <numero>OH041520310BR</numero>
               <sigla>OH</sigla>
               <nome>ETIQUETA LOGICA SEDEX</nome>
               <categoria>SEDEX</categoria>
               <evento>
                  <tipo>RO</tipo>
                  <status>01</status>
                  <data>23/05/2019</data>
                  <hora>15:56</hora>
                  <descricao>Objeto encaminhado</descricao>
                  <local>CEE TERESINA</local>
                  <codigo>64019976</codigo>
                  <cidade>TERESINA</cidade>
                  <uf>PI</uf>
                  <destino>
                     <local>AVALIACAO - RECEITA ESTADUAL</local>
                     <codigo>00004999</codigo>
                     <uf>BR</uf>
                  </destino>
               </evento>
            </objeto>
         </return>
      </ns2:buscaEventosResponse>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Alguém tem consegue dar alguma luz sobre esse assunto?

Desde já obrigado!

Comment: Para quem tiver um problema parecido, descobri a causa: comentei a linha abaixo, antes da declaração da ArrayList <destinos>, e o problema foi resolvido.

   `//@XmlElement(namespace = "http://resource.webservice.correios.com.br/")
    protected List<Destinos> destino;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para quem tiver um problema parecido, descobri a causa: comentei a linha abaixo, antes da declaração da ArrayList , e o problema foi resolvido.

```
//@XmlElement(namespace = "http://resource.webservice.correios.com.br/")
protected List<Destinos> destino;
```